# jQuery UI Slider each value switch class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery UI Slider that has a range between 1-100. I want to change the class of a div for each value between 1-100.

How can I most efficiently go through every value between 1-100 and switch a new class for every value?

Answer (this is what eventually worked out):

```
$( '#slider-container' ).slider({
min: 1,
max: 100,

slide: function() {

    var $activeBackgroundUrl = $('.position_100').css('background');


    return function(event, ui) {
        activeBackgroundUrl = 'url(images/numbers/1'+(ui.value < 10 ? '0' : '')+ ui.value +'.png)';
        $('.position_100').css('background', activeBackgroundUrl);
    };

}()

});
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what it is you want.  Are you saying that every time the slider changes a value, e.g. from 47 to 48, you want to change the class of a particular DIV?

Comment: may I ask what the differences are in each of these classes? in this one case, would it make more sense to actually change individual css properties instead?

Comment: Yes. EG: Slider slide from 1-5; another div uses background images that change with each new class. .number_101 - image of number 1, .number_102 - image of number 2...

Comment: Changing class or changing the background image will do the same thing. Unless changing the background image is more efficient than changing the class, I say just switch the class.

Comment: @infatti I would imagine that programatically changing the background image would certainly streamline your css file assuming that these images are similarly numbered.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a closure to cache your `div`. This way the DOM isn't queried on every `slide` event. Instead, your `div` is only queried for and defined once.

```
$('#slider-container').slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    slide: (function() {
        var $el = $('#myDiv'),
            activeClass = '';

        return function(e, ui) {
            $el.removeClass(activeClass);
            activeClass = 'number_1' + (ui.value < 10 ? '0' : '') + ui.value;
            $el.addClass(activeClass);
        };

    })();
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing?

Comment: Updated the answer. Is there anything in particular that you don't understand?

Comment: Is activeClass from jquery ui or jquery proper? Also, I am unfamiliar with the last (); What is that doing?

Comment: `activeClass` is just a string that holds the name of the active CSS class. The last `()` immediately calls the function wrapped in parentheses and returns the inside function to the `slide` property.